# Law of Demeter with one-to-many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused about how to avoid Law of Demeter violations with one-to-many associations. Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_many :employees
end
```

I believe that it would be a Law of Demeter violation to do this:

```
organization.address.street_name
```

This could be avoided by having a *address_street_name* method. That's a simple enough solution. But let's say we now do this:

```
organization.employees.each { |employee| puts employee.first_name }
```

This seems to be a violation of the Law of Demeter, though it's not quite as obvious to see. You're still exhibiting knowledge of the internal structure of Employee. What is the best way to avoid this type of violation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of Law of Demeter is to avoid exposing internal state and encourages using a "tell, don't ask" principle, rather than `a.something.do_something`, use `a.do_something` (which could then delegate to its internal member `something`).

With that said, it's not a hard and fast rule that you can never violate. In this case, there's no real way around this since you're not asking employee to do something with its first name, rather you're just querying its first name.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Here's my opinion:

- if you use both your examples in a view, I would say both examples above are ok, as, if you are creating a view that displays information from more than one model, which is quite common I suppose, then why not? It is also obvious that views in rails know a lot about the data structure / the model.
- in the second example, if you iterate (that is, perform some logic) on an element, I would consider putting that into the other class, employees in that case. But again, if that above  it's in the view, I would rather not, especially if that would imply generating html code from a model method. In my opinion, a rails model is more of a data structure than an object as described by Rob Martin in Clean Code in the section Data/Object Anti-Symmetry (P. 95, right before the law of demeter ;-))

Answer (score 0):

The motivation for Law of Demeter is encapsulation, not "reduce dot counting".

It makes most sense for hiding behavior in domain objects, but not so much for displaying data in a view - it's not a rule you can't never break.

This article gives a really good explanation on that subject: [Law of Demeter and Dot Counting](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx)